# How can I separate my data hundred to hundred in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to select data between two numbers, e.g something like this :

```
create proc Mysp_hundred
    @a int
as
    select * 
    from tblPhoneNumber
    where ROW_NUMBER() between @a * 100 and (@a + 1) * 100
```

Here if I set `@a = 1` I should get rows between 100 and 200

How I can do it ?

Comment: which sqlserver version you are using ?

Comment: If SQL Server 2012 checkout OFFSET and FETCH. Demo'd here: http://dbadiaries.com/new-t-sql-features-in-sql-server-2012-offset-and-fetch

Comment: That range would return up to 101 rows if it worked the way you hoped.

Answer (score 3):

Use a subquery:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, row_number() over (order by (select NULL)) as seqnum
      from tblPhoneNumber
     ) t
where seqnum between @a*100 and (@a+1)*100;
```

Note that SQL tables represent unordered sets, so you should have an `order by` to specify the ordering of the data.  In fact, you want a stable sort (no duplicate keys) so you get different rows each time.

Comment: That range will return up to 101 rows.

Comment: @shawnt00 . . . (1) that is the logic in the original question; (2) the OP says "rows between 100 and 200"; (3) I agree with you that the more sensible construct would more like `seqnum between @a*100 + 1 and (@a+1)*100'.

Comment: I'm not suggesting the answer is wrong. I'm just pointing out to OP that it probably still requires a small tweak since it's pretty obvious to all of us what the intent is here.